# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'upload' not found

Tags: php

I am working on my current project and all of the sudden I come across this fatal error which does not make any sense at all to me. I have a bunch of classes in the same folder as my upload class but only when I try to instantiate the upload class i get this error, all the other class work and are found perfectly.

my autoload class:

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');

function __autoload($class_name) {
    $new_class_name = strtolower($class_name);
    $class = explode("_", $new_class_name);
    $path = implode("/", $class).".php";
    require_once($path);
}
```

This is how I am instantiating the upload class among others:

```
<?php

$objForm = new Form();
$objValidation = new Validation($objForm);
$objTalent = new Talent();
$objUpload = new Upload();
```

It is very strange how all other classes and more than the ones seen here all load perfectly. The page where I am trying to load the Upload class is itself called upload.php Could this be a reason or not, I also tried changing the name to Uploading but still the same error.

Full Error here:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'upload' not found in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/al/pages/upload.php:6 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/inc/core.php(7): require_once() #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/al/index.php(6): Core->run() #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/al/pages/upload.php
>
> on line 6

I am running php 7 on Mac and using MAMP as you can see from the error. I look forward to at least someone pointing me in the right direction and as to why only this class will not load.

Comment: Why are you certain that the upload class file is being loaded? Did you put a `die('foo')` in there, say, to confirm? Or run `class_exists('Upload')`?

Comment: Class names in PHP are case sensitive, file names are case-sensitive on *nix systems.  Notice how it says `Class 'upload' not found` with a lowercase `u`.  You shouldn't be doing strtolower in the autoloader.  Even if you're able to include the file properly, `new upload` is not equal to `new Upload`.

Comment: Yes I understand that but I have tried both ways with a capitol U and the other way round, that does not seem to be the problem

Comment: I changed the autoload class to not strtolower the classes but still no difference i can create a new class and instantiate it but the problem is only with the upload class, i tried to also delete it and create a new one, restarted the server and everything but no difference, any ideas friends?